# Scheme: append to local environment

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

Say, I want to implement "declarative" object system in Scheme by defining object symbol and then appending methods and fields to that object. While doing so, I want to exploit the local environment of this object to properly bind it's fields in methods (which are added later), for instance (a very "hacked-together" example):

```
(define myobj 
(begin
    (define x 5) ; some local field (hard-coded for example)
    (define (dispatch m d)
        (cond ((eq? m 'add-meth) (define localmethod1 d))
              ((eq? m 'inv-meth) (localmethod1 d))))
    dispatch
))
(myobj 'add-meth (lambda (y) (+ y x)) ;want this to bind to x of myobj
(myobj 'inv-meth 3) ;8
```

Don't mind silly dispatching mechanism and hard-coded "localmethod1" :)  Also do mind, that x may not be available during definition of dispatcher.
First of all, I get problems with using define in define (Bad define placement).
Then: how to make sure that x in lambda binds to the right one (inside of myobj) and not to some x in global environment?
Last: Is there a way to mutate such local enivornments (closures, right?) at all?

EDIT2: I know that you can make this with local lists like "fields" and "methods" and then mutate those by a dispatcher. I wanted to know if there is a possibility of mutating local environment (produced by a dispatch lambda).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying:

> x may not be available during definition of dispatcher

and then you are asking:

> Then: how to make sure that x in lambda binds to the right one (inside of myobj) and not to some x in global environment?

The short answer is: *you can't*.

The reason is that (see for instance the [Mit-Scheme manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Static-Scoping.html)):

> Scheme is a statically scoped language with block structure. In this respect, it is like Algol and Pascal, and unlike most other dialects of Lisp except for Common Lisp.
>
> The fact that Scheme is statically scoped (rather than dynamically bound) means that the environment that is extended (and becomes current) when a procedure is called **is the environment in which the procedure was created** (i.e. in which the procedure's defining lambda expression was evaluated), **not the environment in which the procedure is called**. Because all the other Scheme binding expressions can be expressed in terms of procedures, this determines how all bindings behave.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: It's still can be possible. You just need to install `x` into right environment (in which lambda-procedure is defined, if I understand the question correctly). But I haven't seen any Scheme implementation that would give you "local" environment as the first-class object.

Comment: @mobiuseng, it seems to me that the question is about creating an "object" and then adding "fields" and "methods" that refer to those fields,  but at different times. So, methods would be defined without any relation with the definition of fields. I don't think this is possible (however I agree that the question is not totally clear).

Comment: my thinking about it: (hypothetically) we can create an environment, which will be the _object_. Then we can install procedures (AKA methods) and variables (AKA fields) into this environment-object. [MIT-Scheme](http://goo.gl/bGdLvR) gives you the ability to create first-class top-level environments and add procedures and variables into it. But I am not sure how it will work if you have a free variable in the procedure: will it look it up from the place where you define it (i.e. normal top-level), or where you install the procedure to...

Comment: *Just tried: doesn't work*: here is [the example of the code](https://gist.github.com/mobius-eng/72a73f6bd49bf5041591)

Comment: @mobiuseng, I've seen the example. Interesting the fact that environment are first class values. But the example is still impossible, since the point of static scoping is that one cannot write an expression that returns a function with free variables, that will be bound later on (this is possible in Common Lisp, on the other hand, through the use of “special” variables).

Comment: The only way I can think of making it working is to use `eval` with the environment as the second argument. I have updated the code reflecting this. But it has two problems: 1) now environment contains lots of things in order to evaluate `define` form (including a read table); 2) `eval` is a dirty hack.

Comment: @mobiuseng you are thinking in the exact direction, what I've meant (with your example code). And yea, eval with "injected" environment is a hack :( That is why I asked this question in the first place. Sorry, if it was unclearly formulated.
I am actually happy with newly found picoLisp. It has the exact system that I wanted. And I guess, there is no way you can make such thing in Scheme.

Answer (score 3):

`begin` in Scheme does not produce local environment. To introduce local variables use `let`. Or, alternatively define an object, or rather a class to construct the object, as `lambda`-procedure, that will act as a constructor. This will solve your first two problems.

To mutate: you can mutate by having a right dispatch method. For example,

```
(define (make-object init-val)
  (define x init-val)
  (define (dispatch msg)
    (cond ((eq? msg 'inc)
           (lambda (y)
             (set! x (+ x y))))
          ((eq? msg 'x)
           x)
          (else
           (error "Unknown msg"))))
  dispatch)

> (define obj (make-object 10))
> (obj 'x)
10
> ((obj 'inc) 20)
> (obj 'x)
30
```

[SICP, Chapter 3](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-19.html#%_chap_3) provides good examples of how to make objects with local state.

Comment: You construct objects, when you know what to construct. I wanted to play with the idea that object is declared, but fields and methods added later on. So in this case (with your example), x may not even be there yet, so you can't use set! x (...) directly. What to do in this case? (also updated question). I am aware that you may make two lists of fields and methods and use this approach, but I am interested more in local environment mutation.

Comment: OK, I see what you want. In principle, it can be possible (looking at Scheme-interpreter implementation), but I haven't seen in any Scheme implementation that would provide "local" procedural environment as the first-class object. MIT-Scheme provides first-class top-level environments, but this seems too heavy-weight for your purposes.

Comment: @artemonster you write in your update that you know about using lists, etc. so, you just replace the direct `set! ...`, with the indirect `(set-field! ...)` which would use structure-mutating primitives like `set-car!` and `set-cdr!` and identify the field by name, a string.